# i need to use when in sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, case

Please its just a simple question , and i did it before but i cant do it right now .

i need to write when in column in sql view to give me value based on another column

as shown in the pic below

[image]

i need to make a new column to give me a range of total value from 1000 to 2000 to be ' 1000-2000'

i used to write it as shown

when [total] between '1000' and '2000' then '1000-2000' else 'not'

Comment: Are you really using sql server 2005?? Maybe time for an upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `case when expression`

```
case when [total] between 1000 and 2000 then '1000-2000' else 'not' end
```

Answer (score 2):

use case when like below and I'd prefer >= and < rather than between

```
case when total>=1000 and total<=2000 then '1000-2000' else 'not' end
```